# Please fix jarring new page jump when posting comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

There's new behavior on SO, MSO, and here on MSE that is extremely jarring: When you type a comment and press Enter, the page is scrolled so the comment is at the very top, e.g.:

I'm writing a comment:

[image]

And when I press Enter:

[image]

I've replicated it in Chrome and Firefox (both on Linux). This is new, it didn't do this yesterday.

There seem to be other scenarios where interacting with comments makes the page jump unpleasantly as well. What I've found so far *(please add to this list if you find new ones):

- Posting a comment
- Clicking the link to show comments when they aren't showing (e.g., someone comments when you're looking at something, and you want to see it)

Could we restore the old behavior of not scrolling if not necessary, please?

Comment: Happens when you "show more comments", too.

Comment: should be less jarring now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was an unintended and unforeseen consequence of a related change; entirely my bad; fixing...

Comment: Lemme guess: Browsers are trying to move those elements into the view because they're being animated?

Comment: Yikes! Posting this comment also made it scroll ^.

Comment: Seems like on [a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269834/remove-the-annoying-comment-auto-anchor-links) marked as a Dupe you're saying that this is _intended_ behaviour of the Show More Comments link?  Is that behaviour staying then? (Edit: nevermind, just seen your answer on [this cross site-dupe](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310908/show-more-comments-button-has-broken) - will await the further discussion...)

Comment: @James when adding: unintentional; when expanding: intentional - however, I'm disabling it for now

Comment: Yeah, I really wouldn't want it for expanding, either. In general, really, I prefer my page scroll to be under my control, and any scrolling done by a site should **only** be to reveal an element I asked for that isn't visible.

Comment: It has *got* to be nerve-wracking to do live edits on a site like SO. :-) Kudos to you, Marc.