# Remove the annoying comment auto-anchor links

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, scrolling

I am noticing this behaviour since today only. When I post a new comment, the browser window is scrolled down to the comment I just added. Previously, this scroll-down behaviour was reset once the animation for new comment fade effect was finished.

The same happens when I click on `show more comments` button.

Is this a ninja feature being incorporated? If so, it is very annoying.

Comment: should be less jarring now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "when I click on `show more comments` button" thing was very much intentional; the other: not so much - I'll fix the latter immediately, and think about the first one - whether we should revert that, etc

Comment: Is there anywhere we can vote down features we don't like? Such as, for example, jumping around the page just because you click "show more comments"?

Comment: FWIW, the way "show more comments" worked just now for me on Physics is great; highlights the comments but doesn't cause the page to jump.